# JQuery Text Carousel not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JQuery Text Carousel Plugin, this works great in Mozilla but in IE the text scrolls up once and then stops, code is below:

### JQuery Text Carousel Plugin

```
(function($) {

$.fn.testimonialRoller = function(settings) {


    var defaults =
    {

    };

    settings = $.extend(defaults,settings);

    var divHidden = $("<div/>");
    $(this).append(divHidden);
    $(divHidden).css("float","left;");

    var BuildDivTestimonial =  function(description,name, i)
    {


        var divTestimonialContainer = $("<div/>");
        $(divHidden).append(divTestimonialContainer);
        $(divTestimonialContainer).attr("class","divtestimonialcontainer");
        $(divTestimonialContainer).attr("id","divtestimonialcontainer" + (i + 1));

        var divMain = $("<div style='padding-left:32px; padding-top:26px; padding-right:50px '/>");
        $(divTestimonialContainer).append(divMain);
        $(divMain).attr("class","main");
        $(divMain).html("<strong>... “</strong>" + description + "<strong>”...</strong>");

        var divName = $("<div style='padding-left:131px; padding-top:11px '/>");
        $(divTestimonialContainer).append(divName);
        $(divName).attr("class","blue");
        $(divName).html("<strong>" + name + "<strong/>");

    }

    var InitaliseTestimonials = function()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < settings.data.length; i++)
        {

            var description = settings.data[i][0];
            var name = settings.data[i][1];

            BuildDivTestimonial(description,name, i);
        }
    }

    InitaliseTestimonials();


    var currentPosition = 1;
    var countPosition = 1;

    var StartRollover = function(){

        $(divHidden).animate({ marginTop : -120 * countPosition}, 5000, function() {

            //var divTestimonial = $("#divtestimonialcontainer" + currentPosition);
            //$("#divtestimonialcontainer" + currentPosition).remove();
            //$(this).append(divTestimonial);


            var description = settings.data[currentPosition-1][0];
            var name = settings.data[currentPosition-1][1];

            BuildDivTestimonial(description,name, currentPosition-1);

            currentPosition += 1;
            countPosition += 1;

            if(currentPosition > 5)
            {
                currentPosition = 1;
            }

            if(countPosition == 50)
            {
                $(this).css("marginTop", 0);
                countPosition = 0;
            }

            StartRollover();




        });

    }


    StartRollover();


}

})(jQuery)
```

### Installation

```
function TestimonialRoller() {

var arrayTestimonials = [["Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget, elementum vel, cursus eleifend","Patrick Pool"],
                        ["Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget, elementum vel, cursus eleifend","Patrick Pool"],
                        ["Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget, elementum vel, cursus eleifend","Patrick Pool"],
                        ["Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget, elementum vel, cursus eleifend","Patrick Pool"],
                        ["Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget, elementum vel, cursus eleifend","Patrick Pool"]];
$(".testimonials").testimonialRoller({ data:arrayTestimonials });


}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="testimonials">

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.testimonials
{
float:left;
height:240px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.main
{
    font-family:Tahoma; font-size:13px;  color:#25272E; line-height:13px;

}

.blue
{
    font-family:Tahoma; font-size:11px;  color:#004170;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to replace

```
$(divHidden).css("float","left;");
```

with

```
$(divHidden).css("float","left");
```

in the testimonialRoller js file